# Slow update with OrmLite

Tags: android, sqlite, performance, ormlite

I have a simple structure and i noticed that updating records in my database takes too long to execute.

This is how my data class is defined:

```
public static final String TILE_MAP_UNIQUE_ID_FIELD_NAME = "tileMap_unique_id"; 
@DatabaseField (uniqueIndexName = "unique_tileMapCache", canBeNull = false)
int tileMap_unique_id;
public static final String TILE_MAP_LEVEL_ID_FIELD_NAME = "tileMap_level_id"; 
@DatabaseField (uniqueIndexName = "unique_tileMapCache", canBeNull = false)
String tileMap_level_id;
public static final String COLUMN_FIELD_NAME = "column"; 
@DatabaseField (uniqueIndexName = "unique_tileMapCache", canBeNull = false)
long column;
public static final String ROW_FIELD_NAME = "row";
@DatabaseField (uniqueIndexName = "unique_tileMapCache", canBeNull = false)
long row;
public static final String IMAGE_DATA_FIELD_NAME = "image_data";
@DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY, index = true, canBeNull = false)
byte[] image_data;
public static final String IMAGE_DATA_LENGHT_FIELD_NAME = "image_data_lenght";
@DatabaseField (index = true, canBeNull = false)
int image_data_lenght;
public static final String DATE_CREATED_FIELD_NAME = "date_created";
@DatabaseField(index = true, canBeNull = false)
Date date_created;
public static final String DATE_LAST_ACCESSED_FIELD_NAME = "date_last_accessed";
@DatabaseField(index = true, canBeNull = false)
Date date_last_accessed;
public static final String ACCESSED_COUNTER = "accessed_counter";
@DatabaseField(index = true, canBeNull = false)
int accessed_counter;
```

And this is the update statement somewhere in my application:

```
Dao<TileMapCacheData, Integer> updateTileMapCacheDataDao = dbHelper.getTileMapCacheDataDao();
UpdateBuilder<TileMapCacheData, Integer> updateBuilder = updateTileMapCacheDataDao.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(TileMapCacheData.DATE_LAST_ACCESSED_FIELD_NAME, new Date());
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(TileMapCacheData.ACCESSED_COUNTER, record.accessed_counter + 1);
updateBuilder.where()
.eq(TileMapCacheData.TILE_MAP_UNIQUE_ID_FIELD_NAME, tileMap.getUniqueId())
.and()
.eq(TileMapCacheData.TILE_MAP_LEVEL_ID_FIELD_NAME, tileMap.getLevelId(tileImage.tile.level))
.and()
.eq(TileMapCacheData.COLUMN_FIELD_NAME, tileImage.tile.column)
.and()
.eq(TileMapCacheData.ROW_FIELD_NAME, tileImage.tile.row);
updateTileMapCacheDataDao.update(updateBuilder.prepare());
```

The SQL looks like this:

```
UPDATE `tilemapcachedata` SET `date_last_accessed` = ? ,`accessed_counter` = 11 WHERE (((`tileMap_unique_id` = -1902272760 AND `tileMap_level_id` = '5' ) AND `column` = 24 ) AND `row` = -6 )
```

Does any one see where the problem is? 
The .update() takes several seconds and it should be executed instantly.

Any idea would be great.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all @no9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I see is the `byte[] image_data;` field may hold some huge value that is slowing things down.  But the update you show is not even touching the `image_data` field so I have no idea why it is taking so long.

I would recommend enabling some of the logging in ORMLite to see if you can figure out where the time is going. See http://ormlite.com/docs/logging

Also, you have a lot of indexes in this table including and index on the `byte[] image_data`.  You might consider removing some of these indexes unless they are truly necessary.

Comment: partialy. The problem is that on some phones it works ok while on some it works slow.

Comment: Let me know if you figure out the differences.

Comment: If you are using Log4j then you can put a log4j.properties file in your src/main/resources.  The logging docs give some samples: http://ormlite.com/docs/logging